# UIVIewController not displaying

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am performing a push segue, setup via storyboard.

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadResultView" sender:self];`

However the Controller(`ResultController` for future reference) is not getting displayed.

`viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` are getting run on `ResultController` but the controller is not visible. I have checked the view controllers on `self.navigationController` and `ResultController` has been added there.

I have tried linking the segue to either a button or calling via performSegue but same issue.

Any idea what's going on here?

Some more info post my experiments:

- The `ResultController` is displayed if the segue is changed to
  Moda
- Have tried recreating segues several times
- `NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f, %f",self.view.frame.origin.x,
  self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width,
  self.view.frame.size.height);` in the `viewDidAppear` method of
  ResultController gives 0,0,320,480

[image: storyboard]

Comment: Could you post some relevant code please?

Comment: it's just a `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Will post screenshot of storyboard

Comment: is your current `viewController` embedded in a `navigationController` ?

Comment: @GoGreen Yes it is, There are 6 UIViewcontrollers in the navigationController totally. The first 5 segue perfectly fine

Comment: how did you navigate from the other 5 viewControllers?

Comment: @GoGreen same way, with `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: where are you calling the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method?

Comment: A network call triggers the segue, It is not in viewDidLoad or such, my thought is that the old uiviewcontroller that is calling the performsegue is not getting kicked off the displaystack(?) or such and the `ResultController` is underneath it. Is something like that possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46839/discussion-between-gogreen-and-prat)

Comment: Off Topic: Use `NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));` instead of `NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f, %f",self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);`.